# Hiera - variables from hash

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm really terrible at Hiera, I just dont seem to be getting it. I dont know if this is possible but I'd like to provide my class with a hash, something like:

```
modules::unit::filemode::config
 - /usr/bin/ls, root, root, 0775
```

and have it map to

```
file { "$filename":
   owner => $owner,
   group => $group,
   mode  => $mode
}
```

I've tried experimenting with hashes and `$config.each`, but i just cant seem to figure it out.

Any pointers? :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to provide my class with a hash, something like:
>
> ```
> modules::unit::filemode::config
>  - /usr/bin/ls, root, root, 0775
> ```

That's not valid YAML, and the value you appear to be trying to associate with key `modules::unit::filemode::config` doesn't look anything like a hash.  Hashes associate values with keys, so where are the keys?

From the intended usage, I guess you want something more like this:

```
# The value is one hash with keys name, owner, group, and mode
modules::unit::filemode::config:
  path: '/usr/bin/ls'
  owner: 'root'
  group: 'root'
  mode: '0775'
```

or perhaps like this:

```
# The value is hash of hashes; the outer hash has file names for keys,
# and the inner ones have keys owner, group, and mode
modules::unit::filemode::config2:
  '/usr/bin/ls':
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: '0775'
  '/maybe/another':
    owner: 'luser'
    group: 'root'
    mode: '0644'
```

Either one of those could provide data for a class parameter `$modules::unit::filemode::config`:

```
class modules::unit::filemode(
  Hash $config
) {
  # ...
}
```

The former style of data provides information for a single file, and it would make the most sense with that to access the hash members explicitly, by key:

```
file { $config['path']:
  owner => $config['owner'],
  group => $config['group'],
  mode  => $config['mode'],
}
```

Alternatively, because I carefully chose hash keys that match the names of `File` resource properties (including `path`), you could abbreviate that to this:

```
file { $config['path']:
  * => $config,
}
```

It doesn't make much sense to iterate the members in this case because they have little individual meaning, and they are only syntactically, not semantically, comparable.

The latter data layout allows for providing information about multiple files, one for each element of the outer hash.  These outer members *are* semantically comparable, and iterating over them is a likely way to use the data, maybe something like this:

```
$config2.each |$path, $props| {
  file { $path:
    * => $props,
  }
}
```

That declares a `File` resource corresponding to each element of the (outer) hash.